# Is there any way to know if a youtube video display ads? via API?

Tags: api, youtube, ads

Some youtube videos has those ads show up on video at the bottom of the screen. Is there any which I can find out which videos have these kind of ads?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the listener services which have methods such as onAdStarted().
Full dev doc: https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/reference/com/google/android/youtube/player/YouTubePlayer.PlayerStateChangeListener

Comment: this would require me to actually try to play the video correct? i was hoping for more of a meta-data type.

Comment: that's correct. I don't believe there's a direct way to tell whether an ad will play or not.