# disable commercials in YouTube API V3 for Android

Tags: android, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I'm writting an Android App and I'm using YouTube API V3 to let the user to search YouTube for videos and show it to him,
And I would like to NOT have commercials in the beginning of the video.
is there a way todo it? even pay google for it..

Answer (score 0):

Ads are determined by the uploader of the video and are a cornerstone of Youtube's monetization model so it's doubtful that there's a flag somewhere to disable them. I also doubt you'd get far contacting google directly [but you could give it a try](https://www.youtube.com/t/contact_us).

There is a way to check for the existence of ads in a video, so you could try to filter out videos that contain ads.

[Is there any way to know if a youtube video display ads? via API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20551895/is-there-any-way-to-know-if-a-youtube-video-display-ads-via-api)